# meaning of SCRIPTARGS in batch scripting

Tags: shell, batch-file

can anyone please explain the meaning, importance and usafe of "SCRIPTARGS" in batch scripting.
my code in batch for the same is running .. i want a similar function in shell.. any input regarding this is appreciated..
 here is my line of code.

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Sony/Sound Forge Pro 10.0/Forge100.exe" -SCRIPTARGS:"file=output/msvs/%%G.wav&file2=Ref/Generated_Ref_Outputs_MSVS/%%k.wav&file3=result.txt" -SCRIPT:"Bit_diff.cs" -EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

`SCRIPTARGS` has no meaning whatever to `cmd`. No doubt it is of importance to `Forge100.exe` - you need to examine the documentation for that application.

The presence of `%%G` and `%%k` indicate that this command is within at least two nested `for` loops. A single line in isolation is next to impossible to decipher.

You should note that `/` in the windows world is a switch-indicator; `\` is a directory-separator. Often, but not always, windows can make the change. Better to use the correct character.